# PHP T_STRING error when opening a file

Tags: php, syntax-error, parse-error

So I have the following code:

```
$files = array("l01" => "l01.txt", "l02" => "l02.txt", "l03" => "l03.txt", "l04" => "l04.txt", "l05" => "l05.txt", "l06" => "l06.txt");

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $lfile = $_POST["lab"];

    echo $email."</br>";
    echo $lfile."</br>";

    $f = fopen($files[$lfile],'a')
    fwrite($f, $email);
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in blah blah blah
```

the line number giving is the line for the fwrite, but I know the problem in in the fopen line. Can someone tell me how to fix this? I have tried everything I can think of and the best I acomplished was changing the error to a T_ECHO error.

Comment: Whenever you get a parse error, make sure to also check a few lines before what the error message tells you. A parser is sequential, this error message tells you that fwrite was not expected there, because the parser expected (probably) a semi-colon on the previous line.

Comment: Just a suggestion... a good IDE can help you find these easier by lighting up your code in the area of the parse error. I use Netbeans for PHP http://netbeans.org/features/php/ but there are other good ones depending on your taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon on the fopen line

```
$f = fopen($files[$lfile],'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `;` of `$f = fopen($files[$lfile],'a')`

Comment: God! That's such a stupid error I can't believe I missed it. Thanks for the help.